# JS Fullcalendar Drupal 7 : can't click on event to get details

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I'm using Fullcalendar in Drupal 7 and it is working fine.

I have 3 elements in my calendar and I want to get the event details when I click on it.

I see in the status bar of my browser the correct link and it work if I right-click > open in new tab, I can see the page with the event details...

but when I simply left click on the same event.. nothing, no loading of any page. nothing happens. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to enable colorbox module in drupal 7 and configure fullcalander to use colorbox to open the events in a lightbox.

Ref: [Using Colorbox in FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/node/1237762#drupal7)